# Google forms not asking for permissions Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I already looked at all the articles that I could find here, yet I still couldn't solve the problem. My question is how do I make Google App Scripts ask for permission to view certain files. Here's the problem in Google App Scripts:
[image]

Script:

```js
var NamesToDelete = [""];

function moveFiles(sourceFileId, targetFolderId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId);
  file.moveTo(folder);
}

function createFolder(folderName){
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var subFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();
  var doesntExists = true;
  var newFolder = '';
  
  // Check if folder already exists.
  while(subFolders.hasNext()){
    var folder = subFolders.next();
    
    //If the name exists return the id of the folder
    if(folder.getName() === folderName){
      doesntExists = false;
      newFolder = folder;
      return newFolder.getId();
    };
  };
  //If the name doesn't exists, then create a new folder
  if(doesntExists == true){
    //If the file doesn't exists
    newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
    return newFolder.getId();
  };
};

function start(user){
  var body = "Hello " + user + ",<br> Your google drive cleanup has been successfully initiated. <br> Please go to your drive and click the file named 'Delete Me.' Select everything inside (shift+select) and right click it. In the options that come up, click 'Remove.' <br> Thank you, <br> SS Tools" 
  
  body = body + "<br> Words you chose: <br>";
  
  for (var i = 0; i<NamesToDelete.length; i++) {
    body = body + NamesToDelete[i] + "<br>";
  }
  
  var NEW_FOLDER_NAME = "DELETE ME";
 
  var myFolderID = createFolder(NEW_FOLDER_NAME);
  
  var tutorialPicture = UrlFetchApp
    .fetch("https://i.gyazo.com/f8716f9d9b0539506a78fba52e12788b.png")
    .getBlob()
    .setName("How to Delete");
 
  Logger.log(myFolderID);
  
  listFolders(myFolderID)
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: user,
    subject: "SS Tools: Drive Cleanup Successfully Initiated",
    htmlBody: body,
    inlineImages:
    {
      Tutorial: tutorialPicture,
    }
  });
};


function FirstWord(word) {
  var wordLength = word.length
  var firstWord = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
    var c = word[i]
    if (c == " ") {
      break;
    }
    else if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
      continue;
    }
    
    firstWord = firstWord + word[i]
  }
  return firstWord
}

function checkIfDeleteAB(One, Two) {
  var theFirstWord = FirstWord(One)
  if (theFirstWord == Two || theFirstWord == "") {
    return true
  }
  return false
}

function listFolders(parentID, folder) {
  folder = folder || DriveApp.getRootFolder();

  var name = folder.getName();

  var files = folder.getFiles();

  while ( files.hasNext() ) {
    var nextFile = files.next();
    var nextName = nextFile.getName();
    
    var arrayLength = NamesToDelete.length
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      if (checkIfDeleteAB(nextName, NamesToDelete[i])) {
        Logger.log(name + " :: " + nextName);
        //nextFile.setTrashed(true);
        moveFiles(nextFile.getId(), parentID);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();

  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    listFolders(parentID, subfolders.next());
  }
}

function GetResponsesArray(form) {
  var response = form.response;
  var user = response.getRespondentEmail();
  var item = response.getItemResponses();
  var array = item[0].getResponse();
  var word = "";
  var c = 0;
  var done = false;
  
  Logger.log(array)
  
  for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    
    if(array[i] == " "){
      c = 0;
      NamesToDelete.push(word);
      Logger.log(word)
      word = "";
      done = true;
   }else{
      word += array[i];
      Logger.log("Shaping word :: " + word)
      c++;
      done = false;
     }
  }
  
  if (done == false){
    NamesToDelete.push(word);
  }
  Logger.log(user)
  start(user);
}
```

If you can find the answer to my question I would be grateful!

Comment: While images are welcome, [Edit] to Quote the error text as text is searchable. How are you calling the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google gives the [following](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#access_denied_driveapp_or_the_domain_policy_has_disabled_third-party_drive_apps) explanation for the `Access denied: DriveApp`  exception:

> Administrators of G Suite domains have the ability to disable the Drive SDK for their domain, which prevents their users from installing and using Google Drive apps. This setting also prevents the users from being able to use Apps Script add-ons that use the Drive service or Advanced Drive Service (even if the script was authorized prior to the admin disabling Drive SDK).

In other words, it seems like you are not the admin of your domain and the admin had disabled the usage of Drive SDK for you / for the whole doman.

You need to contact the admin and ask him to change permissions.